# Strange networking issue: Cannot log in if computer is on a switch

Tags: windows-7, networking, login

I'm working in a temporary location.  We have a single network drop.

We have a D-Link 5 port switch plugged into the drop, and two desktop computers plugged into the switch without any issues.

Trying to add a 3rd machine (a laptop) results in a error when we try to log in:

```
"The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship"
```

If I unplug the cable from the switch, and plug it in directly to the wall, then I can log in.

Neither of the other two machines, plugged into the same switch, have this problem.  I've tried switching around the ports, different cables, and a different, brand new 8 port switch, and nothing helps:  unless plugged directly into the wall, the laptop cannot log in.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googling I found fixes for the error [here](http://virtualcurtis.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/fix-the-security-database-on-the-server-does-not-have-a-computer-account-for-this-workstation-trust-relationship/) and [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/winserverGP/thread/a1c0bc9f-46d4-42e2-bea6-d75ccab4060e), hope they help.

Comment: Not really the issue - there isn't actually a problem with the domain controller or the local settings, since changing the way the machine connects to the network fixes the problem.

Comment: Well - I figured I had nothing to lose by trying these, and strangely enough it appeared to have fixed the problem.  No idea why having a switch in the network path would affect this, though.